# how to find difference between two time values in android?

Tags: android, datetime, date-difference

```
SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");

try {
    Date date = (Date) format.parse(a);
    Date date1 = (Date) format.parse(b1);
    Date date2 = (Date) format.parse(c);

    long diff1 = date1.getTime()-date.getTime(); 
    long diff2 = date2.getTime()- date.getTime();

    bundle.putLong("df1", diff1);
    bundle.putLong("df2", diff2);

} catch (ParseException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I have tried the above code for finding the difference between two time values but its not working, this error is coming:

```
12-25 09:00:56.537: W/System.err(1642): java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

Answer (score 0):

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date
```

=> Check your import, correct one is `java.util.Date`

Answer (score 0):

you can try to get like below

```
  java.sql.Date date = new java.sql.Date(format.parse(a));
  java.sql.Date date1 = new java.sql.Date(format.parse(b1));
  java.sql.Date date2 = new java.sql.Date(format.parse(c));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use the excellent Joda Time library instead of the flawed java.util.Date and friends. You could simply write

```
import java.util.Date;
import org.joda.time.DateTime;
import org.joda.time.Days;

Date past = new Date(110, 5, 20); // June 20th, 2010
Date today = new Date(110, 6, 24); // July 24th 
int days = Days.daysBetween(new DateTime(past), new DateTime(today)).getDays();
```